# map data type for python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary

I would like to have a map data type for one of my entity types in my python google app engine application. I think what I need is essentially the python dict datatype where I can create a list of key-value mappings. I don't see any obvious way to do this with the provided datatypes in app engine.

The reason I'd like to do this is that I have a User entity and I'd like to track within that user a mapping of lessonIds to values that represent that user's status with a particular lesson id. I'd like to do this without creating a whole new entity that might be titled UserLessonStatus and have it reference the User and have to be queried, since I often want to iterate through all the lesson statuses. Maybe it is better done this way, in which case, I'd appreciate opinions that this is how it's best done. Otherwise if someone knows a good way to create a mapping within my User entity itself, that'd be great.

One solution I considered is using two ListProperties in conjunction, i.e. when adding an object append the key and value to each list; when locating, find the index of the string in one list and reference using that index in the other; when removing, find the index in one, use it to remove from each, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off using another kind, as you suggest. If you do want to store it all in the one entity, though, you have several options - parallel lists, as you suggest, are one option. You could also simply pickle a Python dictionary, assuming you don't want to query on it.

You may want to check out the [ndb](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) project, which supports nested entities, which would also be a viable solution.